# ASP.NET API How to return Post request status with custom message?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, http-post, http-status-codes

I would like to store my Http status and them messages in json file, for example BadRequest status could have 2 different messages: 1. name could not be null , 2. name could not be empty and etc...
        but unfortunatelly I can't solve it, because IHttpActionResult requires to return only status method, how can I add custom message in different case?
         I am geeting error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.StringContent' to
>   'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult'. An explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a cast?)
>   Exceptions class:

```
 public class ExceptionResponse
    {
        public HttpStatusCode ReturnCode { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

post method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] MyRequest myCaseRequest)
    {
        var myObj = new MyObjCase();
        ExceptionResponse data = new ExceptionResponse()
        {
            Message = "Parameter cannont be null",
            ReturnCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
        };

                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
                var jsonCont = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                if (myObj.Name == null || myObj.Name == "")
                    // return BadRequest(); // Before  
                    return jsonCont; // expecting for result
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use HttpResponseMessage. Example [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results)

Answer (score -1):

```
CustomResponseMessage message = new CustomResponseMessage()
{
   Message = "write a something"
};

Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok,message);

//Custom Class
public class CustomResponseMessage
{
   public string Message{ get; set; }
}
```

You can try this.

Comment: Return type must be HttpResponseMessage.